# Take form data, and transfer it to a table using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to take data from a php file and display it on a table. I’ve been trying to iterate through each row of the data, and then append it to the next row in my table, but I’ve hit a roadblock using a forEach loop. Evidentally, I’m not using the loop correctly, and in the console I get an error that states “Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function”.  Can someone point me in the right direction with what exactly I’m doing incorrectly, and/or how I could more easily come to a solution. Also could someone explain to me how I can get the data of this file as its own variable, I’m having trouble doing this for some reason. Forgive me for incorrect terms or some very probable misuse of methods in my code. I don't control this server by the way.

Here is my code for the function when an update button is pressed to update the table.

```
function updateButton(){
    $.get( "php link", function(data, status) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "php link",
          data: data,
          success: data.forEach(function(row) {
            var htmltext = "<tr><td>"+row.lastname+"</td><td>"+row.currentcity+"</td><td>"+row.uid+"</td><td>"+row.ip+"</td><td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>"
              $(("#table1 tbody").append($(htmltext)));
               }),
          dataType: JSON
        });         
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the success method correctly. Something like this :

```
success: function(resultData) {
            resultData.forEach(function(row) {
                console.log(row.lastname);
                console.log(row.currentcity);
                console.log(row.uid);
                console.log(row.ip);
                console.log(row.updateTime);
                console.log(row);
                var htmltext = "<tr><td>"+row.lastname+"</td><td>"+row.currentcity+"</td><td>"+row.uid+"</td><td>"+row.ip+"</td><td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>";
                $(("#table1 tbody").append($(htmltext)));
               });
        }
```

Try to see what is getting as output in the console panel.

Comment: Now I get an error in the console that states "Uncaught TypeError: (o.dataType || "*").toLowerCase is not a function" Don't really know why this is happening

Comment: well what is `o` and what is `o.dataType`?

Comment: I don't have any variables named o. I have no idea what this error means

Comment: May be you are trying to access member which is not there. Check spellings and case of your members in data.

Comment: I have tnoticed you are using camelCasing for updateTime but lowecase for all other currentcity and lastname. Is it lastname or lastName ?

Comment: In the php file it is lastname. I checked to make sure all the calls were correct and they are. I am trying to take only certain variables in each row of the php file, could that affect this? There are other variables in the data I am  not using in my table. It says the error is occuring in jquery.min.js:4

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.....

```
function updateButton(){
    $.get("php link", function(data, status){
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          url: "php link",
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {
            $.each(data,function)(index,row){
            var htmltext = "<tr><td>"+row.lastname+"</td><td>"+row.currentcity+"</td><td>"+row.uid+"</td><td>"+row.ip+"</td><td>"+row.updateTime+"</td></tr>"
              $(("#table1 tbody").append(htmltext));
            });
          }
        });     
        });
```